# ClassImp preprocessor macro in ROOT - Is it really needed?

Tags: root-framework

Do I really have to use the `ClassImp` macro to benefit the automatic dictionary and streamer generation in ROOT? Some online tutorials and examples mention it but I noticed that simply adding the `ClassDef(MyClass, <ver>)` macro to `MyClass.h` and processing it with `rootcint/rootcling` already generates most of such code.

I did look at `Rtypes.h` where these macros are defined but to follow preprocessor macros calling each other is not easy and so, it would be nice if experts could confirm the role of `ClassImp`. I am specifically interested in recent versions of ROOT >= 5.34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I got on roottalk mailing list confirming that the usage of `ClassImp` is essentially outdated.

> ClassImp is used to register in the TClass the name of the source file
>   for the class.  This was used in particular by THtml (which has now
>   been deprecated in favor of Doxygen).  So unless you code/framework
>   needs to know the name of the source files, it is no longer necessary
>   to have ClassImp.
>
> ClassDef is necessary for class inheriting from TObject (or from any
>   classes that has a ClassDef).  In the other cases, it provide
>   accelerator that makes the I/O slightly faster (and thus is
>   technically not compulsory in this case).   It also assign a version
>   number to the schema layout which simplifies writing schema evolution
>   rules (on the other hand, there is other alternative to assign a
>   version number to the schema layout).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? The `ClassImp` and `ClassDef` macros add members to the class that provide [Run-Time Type Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) and allow the class to be written to root files. If you are not interested in that, then don't bother with these macros.

I never use them.

Comment: I am very well aware why we need to use ClassDef. I just wanted to confirm that ClassImp is not doing anything useful. In fact, this has been confirmed on the roottalk mailing list and I will post their answer here. PS. I/O is perhaps the best part of ROOT